# Distribution Certificate vs live app in App Store

Tags: ios

I have a live app on App Store, but found that the distribution certificate for it has been revoked by someone and we don't know who is it.

Is it possible to generate new distribution certificate for it without affecting currently live app on App Store? Or is it better to revoke and re-generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revoke a Distribution certificate without affecting apps in the App Store. Once it's revoked you can generate a new one that can be used to sign a new build for submission.

Comment: How if I generate new distribution certificate? So there will be 2 dist cert.

Comment: Apple lets you add up to two Distribution certs at a time so you can create a new one before the other expires.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right — revoke the distribution certificate then re-create it.

Generally you would follow this protocol when:

```
  1. You no longer need them.
  2. There's code signing issues. 
  3. You suspect that they have been compromised.
  4. Team members no longer work on your project.
```

> **Revoking development or distribution certificates doesn’t affect apps that you’ve submitted to the store nor does it affect your
>   ability to update them.**

The entire procedure is explained in more detail here:

↳ [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates: Revoking Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW26)